# How to convert markdown to pdf in command line

Tags: linux, shell, pdf, pdf-generation

I need to convert the GitHub README.md file to pdf. I tried many modules, those are not working fine. Is there any new tool to get the exact pdf format. In this website is providing good conversion format of pdf. http://www.markdowntopdf.com/
I need command line tool like this format.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Or maybe [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 17):

## Pandoc

I've personally liked using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) as it support a wide range of input and output formats.

### Installation

Pandoc is available in most repositories: `sudo apt install pandoc`

### Usage

Sometimes, pandoc can tell the formats to use which makes converting easy. However, I find that this often interprets the input format as plain text which might not be what you want:

```
pandoc README.md -o README.pdf
```

Instead, you might want to be explicit about the input/output formats to ensure a better conversion. In the below case, I'm specifically claiming the README.md is in Github-Flavored Markdown:

```
pandoc --from=gfm --to=pdf -o README.pdf README.md
```

Again, there are quite a few different formats and options to choose from but to be honest, the basics suffice for the majority of my needs.

Comment: pandoc does not seem to process <img> tags. okular will read md files and on export does produce pdf with images

Comment: if one want to spend a hour fighting unicode/font problems, pandoc is a perfect choice

Answer (score 11):

Try this software:
https://github.com/BlueHatbRit/mdpdf

Or explain what tools you've tried and why those are not working fine.

Also check this question on superuser:
https://superuser.com/questions/689056/how-can-i-convert-github-flavored-markdown-to-a-pdf

Comment: I prefer Pandoc (because it is a Swiss knife to convert files) https://superuser.com/a/715340/791887

Comment: I can't get `mdpdf` to work--not sure if it's an installation error or what. `$ mdpdf README.md` --> `Error: Browser is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install" at ChromeLauncher.launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdpdf/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:236:15)`. Giving up and trying one of the other options at the superuser Q&A you posted in your answer.

Comment: it just works, thanks!

Comment: Instantly worked for me too. Thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 3):

I found [md-to-pdf](https://github.com/simonhaenisch/md-to-pdf) very useful.

```
  Examples:

  – Convert ./file.md and save to ./file.pdf

    $ md-to-pdf file.md

  – Convert all markdown files in current directory

    $ md-to-pdf ./*.md

  – Convert all markdown files in current directory recursively

    $ md-to-pdf ./**/*.md

  – Convert and enable watch mode

    $ md-to-pdf ./*.md -w
```

And many more options.